# Is there any way to invoke "didSet" of object from within the object itself?

Tags: swift, didset

I have this code:

```
class Child {
    var data : String?;
    func updateData (s: String) { data = s; }
}

class Parent {
    var tableView : UITableView?
    var child : Child? { didSet { tableView.reloadData(); } }
    func updateChild { child?.updateData("Hello!"); }
}
```

How so that calling `child?.updateData()` can also invokes the `didSet` (because `child?.updateData` updates some part of child)? Thanks.

Comment: that is not what `didSet` is for. For observing change / getting notified about changes you should either use delegation or KVO.

Comment: @Chen You can save yourself some typing by omitting the semicolons.

Comment: @Wukerplank but I don't want to lose my "auto-semicolon" habit because I sometimes must do programming in Obj C.

Comment: It's a matter of taste, of course. I still prefer to have idiomatic code.

Comment: @Wukerplank of course. but AFAIK, swift still make use of semicolon to separate between one statement to another, if the coder decides to put multiple statements in a line, and I sometimes do that. so in a sense, semicolon is still interpreted or takes role as a closer in a statement. using semicolon give sense of security to me that the previous line of code won't be interpreted as it runs off to includes the next line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in this case is no, because `child` is an instance of a class, so it is a reference type. `parent` effectively holds only a pointer to `child` which doesn't change when `child`s content changes.

If `child` was a `struct` you would have to make `updateData` mutating and calling it would make `didset` fire in `Parent`

```
struct Child {
    var data : String?;
    mutating func updateData (s: String) { data = s; }
}

class Parent {
    var tableView : UITableView?
    var child : Child? { didSet { tableView.reloadData(); } }
    func updateChild { child?.updateData("Hello!"); }
    init() { 
        child = Child()
    }
}

let p = Parent()

p.child?.updateData("foo") // will fire didSet

if let childUnwrapped = child {
    var varChild = childUnwrapped
    varChild.updateData("bar") // won't fire because of copy semantics
```

Comment: I will never understand why people in their examples love explicitly unwrapping an optional risking a crash rather than using optional chaining which fails gracefully and safely. mystery.

Comment: @holex It's just an example. And, in this case which I wrote in Playground it definitely won't crash. However, for you, I'll change it.

Comment: I know that... but people are usually here to _copy_ and _paste_ the examples into their projects as is, rather than understanding the concept and tailor it :(

Comment: @holex I also don't agree that optional chaining *necessarily* fails safely. If the programmer has made an assumption that the variable is non nil when he updates it, optional chaining hides the incorrectness of the assumption. Using `!` is a shorthand way of providing a precondition or a guard with a fatal error.

Comment: in my view the end-user cannot be punished by a crashing app just because the developer has made mistakes or logical errors in the workflow; in such situation the end-user could be notified about incorrectness and the application itself should correct the problem under the hood for the flawless UX.

Comment: @holex and then you expect the end user to notify the developer about a bug? A crash + crash report is far more useful for me as the developer. You cannot correct the application on the fly in most cases - if you could and have created a way for the application to do that, it no longer is an actual bug / problem. But if a variable has to be set and it *somehow* has not been a crash is what I want my application to do, so that I see it as soon as possible and can fix it as soon as possible, hoping that it never actually reaches the client.

Comment: @holex My view is that an app that fails silently can be more dangerous than an app that fails hard. For a start, the error is less likely to be picked up in testing and secondly, failing silently may introduce subtle hard to find errors into the user's data.

Comment: I don't understand the concept of bug – I've seen a lot but I have never understood how those are created, apart from negligence; a stable app can be developed on a very simple way: it is supposed handle every potential _input_ and manages generating _output_ for those; if that simple condition is not satisfied that means the dev is no longer in control and let the app goes into uncontrolled state, what could be easily unstable and lead crashing, so explicitly unwrapping optionals is exactly that situation :)

Comment: @holex If the developer has lost control of his application, it is not safe to carry on. Let's say you have written an app to do your taxes and you make an incorrect assumption about whether an optional is null. Is it better for the app to fail hard or fail silently and potentially file an incorrect tax return?

Comment: let's say, if an optional __can__ be `nil` and I'd ignore to handle that kinda _input_ value, that is pretty much my fault – regardless whether my ignorance was _intentional_ or _accidental_, that would indicate I might not have done my job thoroughly and I only punish the end-user by the consequences of my ignorance; not talking about that scenario would be quiet far from a situation which the app could not manage: if the OS cannot load one of my resources due to no memory can be allocated, I'd rather let the app crash but that situation is not one of I'd be able handling in the app's scope.

Comment: @holex Before we go any further in this discussion. Tell me, is it more punishment to the user for their tax program to crash or for their tax program to submit an incorrect tax return?

Comment: I see your problem from a different angle: if the value __cannot__ be `nil` then the app needs to force the end-user to fill the value up as a _mandatory field_ – if the dev let the end-user _not_ to fill a mandatory field and still let the incorrect figures get calculated, that failure is nothing to do with the end-user, therefore punishing the end-user by a crash is kinda harsh in such situation because it gives the impression of _"I don't care about collecting the mandatory inputs from you but if you don't provide it, you'll suffer from the consequences"_. sounds like a horrible UX.

Comment: @holex Sorry but please answer my question before carrying on.

Comment: @JeremyP, I just did.

Comment: @holex No you didn't, you just talked about bad UI design. The answer should be yes or no.

Comment: due respect, I talked about UX, not UI – those are not the same thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158701/discussion-between-jeremyp-and-holex).

Comment: Btw, don't worry, I tend to (over)use optional chaining in my codes, to minimize the risk of unwrapping nil values, and use `guard`s to unwrap values that I absolutely need to be exists in order to perform a function. Thanks everyone.